# How can I get arrow functions working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Getting my head around ES6 and was wondering how to create an arrow function which you can debug:

```
 <button onClick={() => this.setState({open: !open})}>Toggle</button>
```

How can I put a console.log in here to see whether this has been triggered or not?

Comment: I don't think this `onclick={` syntax is going to work in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Braces`{}` for a arrow function which will have a block of code.

```
<button onClick={() => {console.log('hello');this.setState({open: !open})}}>Toggle</button>
```

Formatted

```
 <button onClick={() => {
       console.log('hello');
       this.setState({open: !open})
    }}>
      Toggle
    </button>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make it call a separate function, which console.logs and sets the state:

```
<button onClick={this.potato}>Toggle</button>

function potato() {
    console.log('bombs away');
    this.setState({open: !open})
}
```

Or you could put a print statement in the render function, since whenever you update the state it triggers a re-render

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid HTML. The value of the `onClick` attribute needs to be a string, so it should be

```
<button onClick="() => this.setState({open: !open})">Toggle</button>
```

However, this will also not do anything, because merely executing a function declaration will not do anything. You probably just want

```
<button onClick="this.setState({open: !open})">Toggle</button>
```

Now it's easy enough to stick in a `console.log`:

```
<button onClick="console.log("here!"); this.setState({open: !open})">Toggle</button>
```

Of course, you are advised not to do things this way anyway. You should use `addEventListener` to set up the event handler. So it could be

```
const handler = () => this.setState({open: !open});
button.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

If you want to add a console.log to `handler`, as mentioned in another answer, you can either abandon the concise body form (without curly braces):

```
const handler = () => { console.log("here"); this.setState({open: !open}); };
```

Or, although not generally advised, you could use the comma operator:

```
const handler = () => (console.log("here"), this.setState({open: !open}));
```

The following idiom is also somethings useful:

```
const handler = () => console.log("here") || this.setState({open: !open});
```

which works because `console.log` returns `undefined`. This way, you can remove the log by simply deleting the characters `console.log("here") ||` without worrying about fixing up braces and parens.